# Is that deadlock solved (dining philosophers)?

Tags: java, deadlock

I have to solve the deadlock on the dining philosophers problem and while I think I did it, I am unsure if there is still a problem that I didn't see yet. My solution is quite simple which makes me insecure.

Here is the part of my chopstick class that I locked:

```
    boolean inUse;
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void pickUp() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (isInUse()) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            setInUse(true);
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

I used the ReentrantLock to make sure that two threads can't pick up the chopstick simultaneously. So even if the schedule assigns another thread to run, the lock will avoid that it can pick up this chopstick. My solution now is to to do this:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                leftChopstick.pickUp();
                if(!rightChopstick.inUse) {
                    rightChopstick.pickUp();
                    eat();
                    rightChopstick.putDown();
                }
                leftChopstick.putDown();
                think();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When the right chopstick is already in use, the thread releases the left chopstick.

Does this work? Is releasing the used resources a bad idea to solve a deadlock? Is there still a deadlock I didn't see yet?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete source code.

Comment: A mutex for each chopstick is one of the solutions of the problem. There is a few theoretical problematic scenario for deadlock but that never happens in practice due to some amount of randomness involved in threads. Consider the case where all threads took their left chopstick then preempted, Then all threads check if the right chopstick and see it is not available. As I said it will not happen in practice. Check out here http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/classes/cs560/560/notes/Dphil/lecture.html, you solution is solution #2